# doc indexing - how to detect and store new followers and people stopped following

Tags: database, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm indexing a list like this:

```
doc_userid123
{
    followers:[
        {id:5, name:'john'},
        {id:6, name:'mari'},
        {id:7, name:'bart'}
    ]
}
```

So, now I want to **update this list everyday and detect new following people and stopped following**.

The problem is the list can have millions of ID's, so comparing entire list will consume many RAM and take too long time to complete.

One possible way is indexing one doc per day, like this:

```
doc_userid123_2014-29-04
{
    followers:[...]
}
```

But this will store many repeated info.

I'm trying a better way to store this info without over consume RAM/CPU/disk. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new index per day, in this way you can query each day separately or all of them. This is also what [logstash](http://logstash.net/) is doing by default when combined with ElasticSearch.